# Google App Engine custom 404 page for static files

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

I'm working on a GAE application which largely consists of static content. I've configured the following handlers:

```
- url: /content/(.*\..*)
  static_files: static/content/\1
  upload: static/content/(.*)

- url: /content/(.+)
  static_files: static/content/\1.html
  upload: static/content/(.*)\.html
```

The first handler is used to serve images, stylesheets, etc.; the second handles plain URLs like `/content/zoo/monkeys/george` and serves a corresponding HTML file.

Right now, GAE is returning an empty page if there is no corresponding static file for a URL. I'd like to set up a custom 404 page for these cases, but apparently this is not straightforward.

Answers to similar questions suggested putting a "catch-all" handler on the bottom of my `app.yaml`, with a `RequestHandler` that generates the error page.
However, `/content/(.+)` matches all URLs under `/content/`, valid or not, which means such a handler won't get invoked.

I can only think of two other solutions:

1. Route all requests through a dynamic handler, which writes out content for valid URLs, or an error page for invalid ones. I don't like this, because it is far less efficient than letting GAE serve the static files.
2. Declare a separate static handler that explicitly matches *each* static file, and then put a "catch-all" handler at the bottom -- I don't like this either, because it would result in a long list of handlers.

Is there another way to set up a proper 404 page for this case?

Comment: I think you have painted yourself into a corner.   Appengine isn't designed with this use case in mind.

Answer (score 7):

Answer to an old thread for those that would find it useful.

1. Add `require_matching_file: true` as the last property of the handler.

   If there is no corresponding file, the next handler in the waterfall will be invoked, instead of generating the default `404` page.
2. Then add a new catch-all section at the bottom of `app.yaml` with a dynamic handler that processes invalid URLs

Example:

```
- url: /content/(.*\..*)
  static_files: static/content/\1
  upload: static/content/(.*)
  require_matching_file: true

- url: /content/(.+)
  static_files: static/content/\1.html
  upload: static/content/(.*)\.html
  require_matching_file: true

- url: /.*
  script: auto
```

This way GAE will serve all existing static assets through the first 2 handlers. The dynamic handler will be invoked only for non-existing URLs. You will need to write the code for that obviously...

One big disclaimer here : `require_matching_file` is undocumented. But it turns out that GAE adds that field automatically to your `app.yaml` when you upload it.

Comment: I don't know how you found out about this but thanks!

Comment: Not having success with this—I'm guessing `require_matching_file` is no longer used, or this only works with `static_files` but not `static_dir`.

Answer (score -1):

Try 'error_handlers'.

```
error_handlers:
 - file: custom_404.html
```

From [GAE App.yaml documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appref#syntax) - Each file entry indicates a static file that should be served in place of the generic error response. If you specify a file element without a corresponding error_code element, the static file will be the default error page for your app.